# EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on e

Tags: meteor, angular, angular2-meteor

I tried to deploy an **angular2-meteor** project on **meteor server**.

The app works well locally. And I already did `meteor reset` before deploying.

Right now it shows a blank page and error:

> EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on e

I also tried add `https`, but same error. What does this error mean? Or what can possibly cause this? Thanks

Please open [this page](http://lfxkptgsngsqbauxtx.meteor.com) and see Console for more error details.

**UPDATE**: [log file](https://github.com/Hongbo-Miao/meteor-log/commit/e9ad7d474f3737c206b8d7c4c412228a7d45df71) I got using `meteor logs xxx`.

Comment: Hard to tell without seeing the code. Did you list something in `directives:` that isn't a `@Directive()` or `@Component()`? Maybe a pipe?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer like `directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]`? i have them, and i also have pipes

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer thanks, I found why it shows this, I wrote in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I found why it shows these errors.

If you met similar problems like these:

> EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on e

Or

> ngDoCheck is not a function when using minified bundles

They are all related with **UglifyJS**. Right now there is no good way to solve them.

Check [here](https://github.com/Urigo/meteor-angular2.0-socially/issues/36) and [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6380)

Answer (score 0):

You should include `-dev.js` files (for example `angular2.dev.js`) for Angular2 so you'll be able to see more readable errors and especially on which class you have the problem...

```
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/rxjs/bundles/Rx.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/angular2.dev.js"></script> <-----
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script> <-----
<script src="node_modules/angular2/bundles/http.dev.js"></script> <-----
```

Most of time, you have such error when providing something wrong in the `directives` attribute of a component. For example providers...

Comment: I didn't get it, can you give more info? what are `-dev.js files`? thanks

Comment: oh, angular2-meteor app does not have have these.. and I don't know where I can write these.. But I added the log file in my question.

Comment: okay it only contains minified files for Angular2 so you lose the "actual" class the error is about :-(

Comment: Could you list what you defined for all your components within their `directives` attributes?

Comment: oh, I saw some errors in the log like `Error: Email already exists`, `ERROR Application crashed with code: 8`, I will try to solve them first. Hmm.. what do you mean `I defined for all my components within their directives attributes`? I have over 30 components right now, and almost every file has `directives: [AbcComponent]`..

Comment: If `AbcComponent` is a component or a directive that's fine but I guess that there is at least one that isn't. Perhaps you could have a look at them again...

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace around your error message? Is there some elements you can click on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104322/discussion-between-hongbo-miao-and-thierry-templier).

Comment: thanks, I found why it shows this, I wrote in the answer.